# How to vectorize for loops in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have a matrix where each row is a vector of data points and I want to predict labels for each row using a classifier. What I'm doing now is reading each row of the matrix one by one in a for loop and running the classifier on each entry. There's room for parallelization here since each row's outcome is independent of the other rows. Does MATLAB have any function to speed this up?

Comment: Show... us... some... code...

Comment: have you ever tried reading http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wrote the classifier yourself this is possible. Instead of passing one row to the classifier you would pass the complete matrix. Within the classifier you would have to change the way the prediction is made. Assuming you use a mathematical formula to calculate the outcome you would have to alter it using element-wise operators. An example of using element-wise operators instead of a for-loop:

Example data

```
a = [1,2;
     3,4;
     5,6]
```

Using a for-loop

```
p1= zeros(size(a,1),1);
for i=1:size(a,1)
    p1(i) = a(i,1)*2 + a(i,2)^2;
end
```

Using vectorization

```
p2 = a(:,1).*2 + a(:,2).^2
```

Element-wise operators:

http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html?searchHighlight=element-wise

http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html?searchHighlight=element-wise

It is highly recommended to use vectorization instead of for-loops since it's much more efficient.